# How can I pass a date string into a NSLocalizedString variable?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a localized string indicating when a last sync took place, but either way I pass the string, it shows up as a number.

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
let formattedDate = df.string(from: date)
let loca = NSLocalizedString("lastSynced", value: "Last synced %d", comment: "Label showing when the last sync took place ")
return String.localizedStringWithFormat(loca, formattedDate)
```

The result if this is:

```
Last synced 3,322,240
```

But If I drop i18n, and just use this it works

```
return "Last synced \(df.string(from: date))"

--> Last synced 07/01/2022 08:20
```

I've searched the forum here, but not found any post that handles date. I've also tried a lot of other options, e.g

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString("lastSynced", value: "Last synced %d", comment: "Label showing when the last sync took place "), formattedDate))
String(format: NSLocalizedString("lastSynced", value: "Last synced %d", comment: "Label showing when the last sync took place "), df.string(from: date)))
String(format: NSLocalizedString("lastSynced", value: "Last synced %d", comment: "Label showing when the last sync took place "), "\(formattedDate)"))

But all results are in numbers, and also different
Last synced 25504784
Last synced 25495040
Last synced 3068992
```

What essential am I missing here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `"Last synced %d` => `"Last synced %@`, that should be better for a String placeholder.

Comment: @Larme Convert it to an answer, and I'll make it the correct one. Didn't know the placeholder syntax was important, but it solved the issue :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson you should use date and time style when displaying a localized date not a fixed date format.

Comment: I am saying that locale current is not enough when localizing a date if you use a fixed date format

Comment: Note also that current locale is the default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Larme had the correct answer here. I needed to change the placeholder from %d which is for unsigned Int to %@ for strings.

The different format specifiers can be found here
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html